# Android app crashes with exception - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.View.isInLayout()' on a null object reference in MAUI

Tags: android, multithreading, maui

I am developing Android app using MAUI.

I have Request screen where I am showing list of requests.

I am using Segment control having 3 tabs for 3 request types.
When user tap on segment control’s tab, respective requests list gets loaded.
Here I am using CollectionView to show list of requests.

[image]

If user tap continuously on that tabs and icon which is placed near text ‘Awaiting’ (On click of Info icon, there is popup with details and close button) in screenshot faster then app crashes with exception -

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.View.isInLayout()' on a null object reference.

at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.StaticMethods.CallStaticVoidMethod(JniObjectReference type, JniMethodInfo method, JniArgumentValue* args) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:line 13250
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.InvokeVoidMethod(String encodedMember, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.cs:line 41
   at Microsoft.Maui.PlatformInterop.RequestLayoutIfNeeded(View view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\obj\Release\net6.0-android\generated\src\Microsoft.Maui.PlatformInterop.cs:line 421
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ViewExtensions.InvalidateMeasure(View platformView, IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\ViewExtensions.cs:line 258
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler.MapInvalidateMeasure(IViewHandler handler, IView view, Object args) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandler.cs:line 271
   at Microsoft.Maui.CommandMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass6_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.IViewHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v, Object o) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\CommandMapper.cs:line 89
   at Microsoft.Maui.CommandMapper.InvokeCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView, Object args) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\CommandMapper.cs:line 30
   at Microsoft.Maui.CommandMapper.Invoke(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView, String property, Object args) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\CommandMapper.cs:line 48
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.Invoke(String command, Object args) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Element\ElementHandler.cs:line 90
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.InvalidateMeasureOverride() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\VisualElement\VisualElement.Impl.cs:line 134
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IView.InvalidateMeasure() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\VisualElement\VisualElement.Impl.cs:line 129
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.InvalidateMeasureInternal(InvalidationTrigger trigger) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\VisualElement.cs:line 971
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.OnTextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, Object oldvalue, Object newvalue) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Label.cs:line 367
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueActual(BindableProperty property, BindablePropertyContext context, Object value, Boolean currentlyApplying, SetValueFlags attributes, Boolean silent) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindableObject.cs:line 532
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueCore(BindableProperty property, Object value, SetValueFlags attributes, SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindableObject.cs:line 466
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindingExpression.ApplyCore(Object sourceObject, BindableObject target, BindableProperty property, Boolean fromTarget) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindingExpression.cs:line 160
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindingExpression.Apply(Boolean fromTarget) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindingExpression.cs:line 56
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindingExpression.BindingExpressionPart.<PropertyChanged>b__49_0() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindingExpression.cs:line 750
   at Microsoft.Maui.Dispatching.Dispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<DispatchImplementation>b__0() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Dispatching\Dispatcher.Android.cs:line 22
   at Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:line 36
   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net6.0/android-31/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:line 84
   at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V(_JniMarshal_PP_V callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line 22
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.NullPointerException stack trace ---
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.View.isInLayout()' on a null object reference
    at com.microsoft.maui.PlatformInterop.requestLayoutIfNeeded(PlatformInterop.java:47)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

I am adding my code. Let me know if I am wrong anywhere because of which app crashes.

In RequestsListPage.xaml.cs, I have added segment control’s TabIndexChanged

```
public void SegmentedControlView_SelectedTabIndexChanged(System.Object sender, ProjectName.Mobile.CustomControls.ReqSelectedTabIndexEventRegs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (BindingContext != null)
        {
            ((RequestsListViewModel)BindingContext).SegmentTappedCommand.Execute(e.ReqSelectedTabIndex.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

RequestsListViewModel.cs

```
public ICommand SegmentTappedCommand { get; set; }
SegmentTappedCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand<string>(SegmentTapped);
private async Task SegmentTapped(string arg)
    {
        try
        {
            int selectedIndex = Int16.Parse(arg);
            switch (selectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    requestType = “Request1”;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    requestType = "Request2”;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    requestType = "Request3”;
                    break;
                default:
                    requestType = "Request1";
                    break;
            }

            _currentpage = 1;
            RequestsList.Clear();
            await RequestsListAPICall();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Request List API Call

```
    private async Task RequestsListAPICall()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                var current = Connectivity.Current.NetworkAccess;
                if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
                {
                    IsVisible = true;
                    var result = _requestdataservice.FetchAll(requestType +"/"+ Preferences.Get("userID", string.Empty)+"/" + _currentpage.ToString() + ItemsCount);
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        if (result.Any())
                        {
                            _isdataexist = true;
                            if (RequestsList.Count >= 1)
                            {
                                foreach (var item in result)
                                {
                                    RequestsList.Add(item);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                RequestsList = new ObservableCollection<Request>(result);
                            }

                            RequestsList = new ObservableCollection<Request>(RequestsList.OrderByDescending(d => d.RequestedDate));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _isdataexist = false;
                        }
                    }
                    IsVisible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("No Internet Connection", "Please check your internet connection and try again!", "OK");
                    });

                    IsVisible = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                IsVisible = false;
            }
        });
    }
```

If user clicks on Info icon, opens popup to show request details. Code for this as below:

```
private async Task RequestListTapped(Request arg)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                selectedRequest = new Request();
                SelectedRequest = arg;

                await MopupService.Instance.PushAsync(new RequestDetailPopup(this));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        });
    }
```

Is there any issue with Threading in my code or any hint for this?

Comment: In RequestListTapped, either remove Task.Run, or use Dispatcher to get back on MainThread when PushAsync.

Comment: Thank you so much @ToolmakerSteve. I have removed Task.Run and I am able to caught it Catch block. So App is not crashing but having same exception in Catch.

Comment: Issue is at SelectedRequest = new Request(); OnPropertyChanged event it was crashing.  So I have added each parameter in SelectedRequest like  SelectedRequest = new Request()
                {
                    Id = arg.Id,
                    Name = arg.Name,
                    RequestedDate = arg.RequestedDate}.  It's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Since it only happens if user does multiple clicks quickly, make sure a 2nd request can't run until first is completed.

Simplest "fix" is to discard additional requests:

```cs
private bool IsBusy;
private async Task SegmentTapped(string arg)
{
    if (isBusy)
        return;
    isBusy = true;
    try
    {
        ...your existing code...
    }
    catch ...
    finally
    {
        isBusy = false;
    }
}
```

HOWEVER, this means when they change tabs too quickly, it won't show what it should show on the tab.

**Try this as a test,** to see if it avoids the exception. If so, then you have identified the problem - even though you won't want to use that solution because it isn't showing what is wanted.

---

A more useful fix is to DELAY 2nd request until first is finished.

This is done using a `Queue` or a `BlockingCollection`.
I'll use BlockingCollection, because it automatically waits for next item to be added.

SegmentTapped will simply add the request:

```cs
private BlockingCollection<string> SegmentTaps = new BlockingCollection<string>();

private async Task SegmentTapped(string arg)
{
    SegmentTaps.Add(arg);
}
```

The code you have in SegmentTapped will be moved to a method that removes and acts on one entry:

```cs
private async Task HandleOneTap(string arg)
{
    // Run code on UI thread.
    // MUST "await" - otherwise you'll get the same exception as before.
    await Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(async () =>
    {
        ... the code you have in SegmentTapped ...
    });
}
```

Start a loop processing taps, on a background thread, from the constructor:

```cs
    public RequestsListViewModel()
    {
         ... your constructor code ...

         // DO NOT AWAIT this: we start it, but immediately
         // leave the constructor.
         var consumerTask = Task.Run( async () =>
         {
             try
                {
                    // Consume the BlockingCollection.
                    while (true) {
                        // "Take" blocks this task until a value is available.
                        await HandleOneTap(SegmentTaps.Take());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ...
                }
         });
    }
```

NOT SHOWN: How to terminate ("cancel") "consumerTask" when the page is no longer in use. See [Task Cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited my question. User is clicking quickly on Segment Control tab as well as info icon which displays details of request on popup and close button to close popup.     I have tried 1st solution by adding IsBusy. Unfortunately, it couldn’t work. I also thought this should work as user are not going to tap other request till 1st will not complete.

Comment: For 2nd solution, I am not able to add  await Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(async () =>{  });   as it is giving error, Dispatcher does not contain a definition for DispatchAsync. In code behind file, it is there but not in ViewModel.    So in VM, I tried to add other methods to run code on main thread but not working.   Can you help me which method I need to add instead of Dispatcher.DispatchAsync in VM to run it on Main thread?

Comment: Application.Current.Dispatcher.DispatchAsync. Limitation: Don’t use this on Windows, if app might open multiple windows. (It has to be on dispatcher thread of correct window.)

Comment: I have tried using Application.Current.Dispatcher.DispatchAsync.  But it couldn't work.

Comment: Most of the time it is crashing on info icon which is inside the cell while opening the popup for request type.

Comment: *”it couldn’t work”* - when something doesn’t work, say what goes wrong. Compile error? The original problem still happens, no improvement? Nothing happens / view does not update? something else?