# 2 way bindings Set firing multiple times when set from another property setter (MAUI)

Tags: data-binding, maui

2 Way Binding Issue:

I'm (until recently) a driver developer poking my nose into the world of app development; I will readily admit that my understanding of the proper patterns is extremely limited. My problem today relates to two way bindings. Specifically I have bindings that work perfectly (one-way) with labels but when I change them to Editors I see some wildly incomprehensible behavior. In short my app may scan a barcode, use a regex to break it out into 8 different fields and sets those fields. This part works. However once one of those is a 2 way binding (i.e. with an editor or entry) instead of a label the OnPropertyChanged event for that property fires 4 or 5 extra times with values being passed into the Set function that are clearly part of the whole scan but pieced together in an incomprehensible way.  For instance I may assign BoxNo = 14, then the UI does a get on that property but then we start setting it over and over until I see a value like "2031523969.0 LB 14" which are all piece of the full scan but not necessarily sequential.

The first way I tried to do this is to replace "<Label ..." in my xaml with "<Editor". This is when I first saw the error. I then backed off until I had only one property as an editor, and the rest as labels.

The second thing I tried was to manually specify "Two Way" in the binding ala

```
<Editor x:Name="LotNo"
                       Text="{Binding LotNo, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       BackgroundColor="Chartreuse" 
                       Grid.Row="3"
                       Grid.Column="0"/>
```

The third thing I tried was using "Entry" instead of "Editor" but the problem was identical. I did this both explicitly setting the mode and implicitly setting the mode.

The fourth thing I did was try different properties (i.e. Lot Number instead of Box Number ) with the Entry, while leaving the others as labels, it makes no difference which property is used, all are susceptible to this.

After this I figured it's not a UI problem and started looking in my Barcode object. When ScannedText gets set it had been setting all the other public properties which each raise an OnPropertyChanged event. I tried setting all the private properties in the ScannedText.Set and then calling all the OnPropertyChanged events at the end but that made no difference.

Finally I added checks to my set function to skip raising the OnProperty changed if the property value isn't actually changing

Architecture: I have a MauiProgram.cs which passes scanned data from the datawedge to my helpermodel.ScannedText property. I set a break point at the OnReceive event and I only ever receive data from the scanner once per scan.

Here is the code from my Barcode related to the scanned text

```
public sealed class Barcode : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public event Action OnChange;

        private static Barcode _instance;
        public static Barcode GetInstance()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new Barcode();
            }
            return _instance;
        }

        private string scannedText = "Scan a Bag";
        private string partNo = "";
        private string lotNo = "";
        private string boxNo = "";
        private string netWeight = "";// 0.0m; //includes unit i.e. "lb"
        private string tareWeight = ""; //0.0m;//includes unit i.e. "lb"
        private string grossWeight = ""; //0.0m;//includes unit i.e. "lb"
        private string mfgDateTime = "";
        private DateTime scanTime ;


        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name = "") =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        
        public string PartNo
        {
            get => partNo;
            set {
                if (partNo != value)
                {
                    partNo = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PartNo));
                }
            }
        }
        public string LotNo
        {
            get => lotNo;
            set
            {
                if (lotNo != value)
                {
                    lotNo = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LotNo));
                }
            }
        }
 // ...
 // 6 More properties that look functionally identical to PartNo 
 // ...
public string ScannedText
        {
            //8608970AMUVGN3254  213908  1500  1
            //EVERYONE ELSE -- PN - LOT NUM - NET WEIGHT - BAG NUM
            get => scannedText;
            set
            {
                string pattern = @"(\w+\s+\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+([\d,\.]+\s+\w+)\s+([\d,\.]+\s+\w+)\s+([\d,\.]+\s+\w+)\s+([\d,\/]+\s[\d,\:]+\s\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+";
                Match match = Regex.Match(value, pattern);
                scannedText = value.TrimEnd();
                
                //if this is a proper label, then set all other fields.  
                if (match.Success) 
                {
                    //fill all the other fields. '
                    PartNo = match.Groups[1].Value;
                    LotNo = match.Groups[2].Value;
                    NetWeight = match.Groups[3].Value;
                    TareWeight = match.Groups[4].Value;
                    GrossWeight = match.Groups[5].Value;
                    MfgDateTime = match.Groups[6].Value;
                    BoxNo = match.Groups[7].Value;
                    ScanTime = DateTime.Now;
                }
                else
                {
                    PartNo = String.Empty;
                    LotNo = String.Empty;
                    NetWeight = String.Empty;
                    TareWeight = String.Empty;
                    GrossWeight = String.Empty;
                    MfgDateTime = String.Empty;
                    BoxNo = String.Empty;
                    ScanTime = DateTime.Now;
                }

                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ScannedText));
            }
        }

        public void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();


        public Barcode()
        {

        }
}
```

Here is a snippet from Barcode.cs

My MainPage.xaml.cs is dirt simple

```
    Barcode barcode = Barcode.GetInstance();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = barcode;
    }
```

Here is most of the XAML with a few repeating elements left out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ZebraDatawegeSampleMaui.MainPage"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:scannerwerWithIntent.model">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="5"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Label 
                Text="Scan a Datalogic label"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label Text="Barcode:"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Full Barcode"
                FontSize="8"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
            
            <Label x:Name="ScannerText"
                   Text="{Binding ScannedText}"
                   BackgroundColor="Chartreuse" />

            <Grid VerticalOptions="Fill"
                  HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                  >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text="Part Number:"
                    SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                    SemanticProperties.Description="Part Number"
                    FontSize="8"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    VerticalOptions="End"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                <Label x:Name="PartNo"
                       Text="{Binding PartNo}"
                       BackgroundColor="Chartreuse" 
                       Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                <Label Text="Lot Number:"
                    SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                    SemanticProperties.Description="Lot Number"
                    FontSize="8"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    VerticalOptions="End"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                     />
                <Label Text="Box Number:"
                    SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                    SemanticProperties.Description="Box Number"
                    FontSize="8"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    VerticalOptions="End"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                     />
                <Label x:Name="LotNo"
                       Text="{Binding LotNo, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       BackgroundColor="Chartreuse" 
                       Grid.Row="3"
                       Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Entry x:Name="BoxNum"
                       Text="{Binding BoxNo, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       BackgroundColor="Chartreuse" 
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                       Grid.Row="3"
                       Grid.Column="2"/>
                
            </Grid>
            <Button Text="Use Bag!" 
                    x:Name="Commit"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    Clicked="CommitClicked"
                    />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Now just to add more of my thoughts. It's clear that a 2 way binding is complicated and could easily have an infinite loop when you set the code in text and raises a changed event -> the UI sees the event does a get, updates itself and sends a set command because it's changed but that's clearly not happening and is such a simplistic issue that the designers must have accounted for it.

To be clear the unexpected data is passing through the set parameter, the Change event is being raised, a get happens  and then it starts over with the set being called and I cannot figure out why it's being called or why the value is a substring of the value passed into the ScannedText set event.

Comment: First, make sure you don’t have two two-way bindings to the same property. Assuming you don’t, sounds like a “re-entry” problem. Additional incoming data causes a second Set, before the first Set has propagated through everything it affects. Can you change your implementation, so that Set is done less often? Accumulate data for a second, then Set?

Comment: Steve, so far in my testing all incoming data has come in via the scanner. It's certainly viable to collect from the keyboard but that hasn't been happening. The onReceive function  of the scanner is only hitting once

Comment: The symptom suggests to me that scanner input is causing Set to get called multiple times, too quickly. Ensure that never happens, and the problem might go away.

Comment: I triple checked. All 9 bindings are unique but only 1 binding is currently 2 way because the others are on labels.

Comment: Unique isn’t the point. I would use a high res stopwatch and record the ticks when Set is called. Save each value, compare to previous value. Are there ever two Setter calls close together in time?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the statement that you only see one call per scan. Maybe clone the string, to make sure isn’t a buffer that is getting re-used?

Comment: Another idea. Comment out scanner’s ability to set anything. On a timer, directly call Setter once a second, with string you store from a previous scan. Problem still happen? Goal is to determine whether it really is onpropertychanged going haywire, or something elsewhere.

Comment: That's a good thought. I'll give those a try.

Comment: `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch( () => ScannedText = . . . );`  This helps ensure setter is called at a safe time.

Comment: You appear to be correct. This is clearly an issue with the scanner as everything works as expected with a timer based set of the data. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean it is an issue with scanner. Its possible that the scanner interrupt happens "at a bad time". Try my last comment. If that doesn't fix it, then [use BlockingCollection to queue incoming changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76284531/199364). Similar to `HandleOneTap` there, be sure to wrap `ScannedText = ...` in a Dispatch call. If still not fixed, then add to `// Consume the BlockingCollection` loop, `await Task.Delay(500);`, before `await HandleOneTap`. Tune the value as needed. Your situation is different than that Q&A; the onpropertychanges take time.

Comment: I suspect that onpropertychanges is not thread safe. Goal is to ensure UI has fully updated after one sequence of setter / onpropertychanges, before next setter call is allowed to happen. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any Maui event that will tell us that UI has finished processing all changes and updating the UI. Thus the hack of using a delay.

Comment: Sorry I had a few days vacation. Thanks for your help.  Eventually I realized that the "issues" were only occurring on fields with focus.  In short my broadcast receiver was getting the barcode output and it was being written at the same time to that field.  I found a dirt simple solution in the DataWedge configuration that disables keystroke output and viola, no more issues. You're linked solution with the IsBusy would work if I discarded the secondary inputs but not if I queued them. I think I'd like to have a SetReadOnly method in the UI and trigger it with a MainThread.InvokeOnMainThread()

Answer (score 0):

```
barcodeConfig.PutString("keystroke_output_enabled", "false");
```

fixed my issue. No more dual inputs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).